# php imagecreatefromsting gives warning: Data is not in recognized format

Tags: php, gd

i am trying to create image from url returned by linkshare. while i run my code i get error:

> `imagecreatefromstring`: Data is not in recognized format.

Help me how to generate image from url returned by third party.

Here is my code:

```
$url="http://www.thewatchery.com/images/Z/WINDER-WW-1003-P1-03.jpg";
$contents=file_get_contents($url);
$img=imagecreatefromstring($contents);
$img_path=dirname(__FILE__)."/thumb.jpg"; 
//$img_path="thumb.jpg"); 
imagejpeg($img,$img_path,100);
```

Comment: Are you sure you get the image? HTTP protocols must usually be activated in PHP. Try a `var_dump($contents);` and see if you get any data.

Comment: If you know the mime type you can use `imagecreatefromjpeg` or whichever would match to troubleshoot. Previously I used `is_resource` and `get_resource_type`. Since my upgrade to PHP 8 it seems it won't return a resource anymore. ` get_resource_type(): Argument #1 ($resource) must be of type resource
GdImage given`

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty big file, weighing in at 917KB and 1800x2160. Try saving the file locally first and creating the thumbnail, then move on to obtaining the image remotely. Increase error_reporting with: -

```
error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

You will probably find that you're going to have to use cURL to reliably get the remote image data too, just so you get better information for error handling. Break each step into self contained logical steps, composing as you go and you'll see where the process fails.

Good luck.